# Using sample() with sample space size = 1

Tags: r

I have a list of dates that I wish to sample from.  Sometimes the sample space will just be a single date e.g. sample("10/11/11",1).  The dates are stored as chron objects, so when I have just a single date in my sample space (and only then) sample treats this as a vector (1:date).  The documentation for sample points this out:

```
 If ‘x’ has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of ‘is.numeric’) and
 ‘x >= 1’, sampling _via_ ‘sample’ takes place from ‘1:x’.  _Note_
 that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour when
 ‘x’ is of varying length in calls such as ‘sample(x)’.  See the
 examples.
```

But I didn't see a way to disable this feature.  Is there a workaround or a way to stop it from treating objects of length one as numeric?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `sample` documentation recommends this:

```
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
```

Comment: Always wise to follow the experts.

Comment: Very nice. And your use of `sample.int` actually makes this a bit faster than `sample` on an arbitrary length>1 vector

Answer (score 6):

I would wrap it in an `if` statement, or wrap it inside another function.  For example:

```
mysample <-
function(x, size, replace=FALSE, prob=NULL)
{
  if(length(x)==1)
    return(rep(x, size))

  sample(x, size, replace, prob)
}
```