# unlist creating additional values in R

Tags: r, vector

I am creating random permutations of a vector (using the sample() function) by another variable, block, such that the random permutation is taken for each unique element in the other block. When the unique elements in the block become large, however, the number permutation size changes. I'm unsure if the unlist() function is creating spaceholders or why this might be happening. See the example code below; the dimensions of the permutation using block1 is the length of the original variables, however it is longer for block2. I'm dumbfounded on why the code is doing this; any thoughts?

```
x <- sample(1:3, 250, replace = TRUE)
block1 <- sample(1:20, 250, replace = TRUE)
block2 <- sample(1:100, 250, replace = TRUE)

block_permutation = function(x, block) unlist(as.vector(sapply(unique(block), function(j) sample(x[block==j]))))

perm1<- sapply(1:2, function(i) block_permutation(x, block1))
perm2<- sapply(1:2, function(i) block_permutation(x, block2))

dim(perm1)
dim(perm2)
```

Comment: This code looks more complicated than it has to be. Can you provide a little more clarity about what you are trying to take a permutation of? And to what end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, then your problem is that `sample(5)` actually means `sample.int(5)` and is the same as `sample(1:5, 5)`. So when `x[block == j]` results in a single number, you're not sampling from a single number sequence.

As Aaron points out, this is documented in `?sample` and you should use this function instead of `sample` in your `block_permutation`:

```
resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]
```

Also, the `as.vector` is unnecessary.

Comment: For this issue, also see `resample` as discussed in the documentation for `sample` and in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7548080/210673

Answer (score 1):

@eddi has answered your question about why this is happening. But, the code you're currently using is way to. complicated for what seems to be a very simple task. Consider using the following to perform your permutations.

```
perm1 <- replicate(2, unlist(lapply(split(x,block1), sample)))
perm2 <- replicate(2, unlist(lapply(split(x,block2), sample)))

> dim(perm1)
[1] 250   2
> dim(perm2)
[1] 272   2
```

And, with @eddi's function:

```
perm1 <- replicate(2, unlist(lapply(split(x,block1), resample)))
perm2 <- replicate(2, unlist(lapply(split(x,block2), resample)))

> dim(perm1)
[1] 250   2
> dim(perm2)
[1] 250   2
```