# New variable with uniform random number bounded by constant and second variable value

Tags: r, random

I am trying to create a random number that is between 3 and a number provided by a column max.

Create a sample data frame for reproduction.

```
ID <- c(1:10)
max <- c(5,3,7,6,10,4,3,3,5,6)
df <- data.frame(ID,max)
```

I want a third column that is a random number between 3 and max.

```
  ID max
  1   5
  2   3
  3   7
  4   6
  5  10
  6   4
  7   3
  8   3
  9   5
 10   6
```

I have tried many variations of the following.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
df$rand[i] <- sample((3:df$max[i]),1,replace=TRUE)
}
```

The problem is the random numbers are not with in the bounds of 3 and max.  See row 8.  I set my seed to 1234.

```
   ID max rand
1   1   5    3
2   2   3    3
3   3   7    4
4   4   6    4
5   5  10    5
6   6   4    4
7   7   2    3
8   8   3    2
9   9   5    4
10 10   6    3
```

Thanks for any help here.  I am still learning R and struggling with code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using sample() with sample space size = 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547758/using-sample-with-sample-space-size-1)

Comment: Sample behaves differently when you pass it a vector of length 1 vs a vector with length >1. See the duplicate question and the examples on the `?sample` help page. Also, at least one of your max values is <3, not sure what you expect in that case.

Comment: Yes the negative two was a mistake in the example I made.  I should not have put it there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also keep using `sample` just with some constrains (and avoid using `floor` or `round`)

```
df$rand <- sapply(seq_len(dim(df)[1]), function(x) if(df$max[x] > 3) sample(3:df$max[x], 1, replace = T) else 3)

##   ID max rand
##1   1   5    3
##2   2   3    3
##3   3   7    6
##4   4   6    5
##5   5  10    7
##6   6   4    4
##7   7   2    3
##8   8   3    3
##9   9   5    4
##10 10   6    3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$rand <- sapply(df$max, function(max) round(runif(1, 3, max)))
```

Your 7th row has `max = 2` which is why we get a `NaN`.

```
ID max rand
1   1   5    4
2   2   3    3
3   3   7    4
4   4   6    4
5   5  10    3
6   6   4    4
7   7   2  NaN
8   8   3    3
9   9   5    4
10 10   6    4
```

Comment: Note that this method will give higher probability to numbers between 3 and max than to the end points.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `transform` and take care of the case where the max < 3:

```
 transform(dat,y = sapply(max,function(x)floor(runif(1,3,if(x>3)x else 3))))

  ID max y
1   1   5 4
2   2   3 3
3   3   7 6
4   4   6 4
5   5  10 9
6   6   4 3
7   7   2 3
8   8   3 3
9   9   5 3
10 10   6 3
```

Comment: No, for that it's sufficient to replace `1, 3, max` below with `1, 3, base::max(max, 3)`...

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski well..why not to add this "brilliant" comment to your answer?

Comment: Unsure of OP's intended behavior.