# Select random index in vector which meets requirements

Tags: r, random, vector

I have a vector X of length 1000 containing 10 randomly placed ones and 990 zeros.

I have below function which modifies vector X.

```
foo <- function(X){
    old <- sample(which(X==1),1)
    new <- sample(c(1:1000),1)
    X[old] <- 0
    X[new] <- 1

    return(X)
}
```

Above function does following:

1. Locates the ones
2. Selects the index of one of them at random
3. Selects a random location in X
4. Changes the previously located one to a zero
5. Changes the random location from step 3 from 0 to 1.

With above code, a 1 can be added to a location which already holds a 1. This I don't want to be possible. In other words, I always want to have 10 ones in my vector.

The solution must be without loops because I am calling this function thousands of times, and speed is of the essence.

Comment: What about `new <- sample(which(X==0),1)`?

Comment: That will do it. Thank you

Comment: @lmo Be careful, that will only work if more than one row matches. Look what happens with `X<-c(1,1,1,1,1,0); sample(which(X==0), 1)`

Comment: @MrFlick You are right in general, but in the given problem, there are 990 zeros at all times.

Comment: @MrFlick Actually this causes a problem when I try with only 1 one. How can I solve it?

Comment: @Mongzyy see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547758/using-sample-with-sample-space-size-1

Answer (score 0):

The *new* index has to restricted to values, where X is not 1:

```
  foo <- function(X){
        old <- sample(which(X==1),1)
        new <- sample(c(1:1000)[X!=1],1)
        X[old] <- 0
        X[new] <- 1

        return(X)
    }
```